# Android 3.2 HTTP streaming

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming

I'm trying to create an app to stream live TV. Currently the problem I'm facing is that after say 10 minutes of playing, the video will freeze but the audio will carry on. This is on a 1.3mbps stream. I also have lower streams, such as a 384kbps stream, that might last an hour or so, but will still do the same. I've tested this with a local video, that is high quality (file size is 2.3gb) and that has no lag and doesn't freeze at all, so it must be something to do with the way HLS is streamed to android.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Thanks